# JqueryDatatable Custom Filtering by column

Tags: javascript, datatables

Hi I'm using Jquery datatable. It works fine with simple datatable.It can search and order by columns
The link i'm using

```
 <link href="~/content/vendor/DataTables-1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="~/content/vendor/DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

So I want to add some extra button.
1.Filter by selected item from dropdown.
2.Filter by daterange
3.PDf and Excel export.

I tryed this examples but none of them reacted a bit. It just like nothing added.

1. This link makes dropdown but it not shown on my table.
   http://live.datatables.net/tamixov/1/edit

2.This makes date range but i can't make it with my databesle. I copy apsted the js code
http://plnkr.co/edit/mdeEYoZtnvpfHCdtSxDP?p=preview&preview

3.In js file

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             
           
              //zero confg. datatable. It works
            $('#datatable-table-4').DataTable({
                responsive: true,
                "order": [[5, "desc"]],
                //But I need to add theese.buttons are not showing but in this example it shows
//https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html
                buttons: [
                    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                ]
            });
```

below js in html

```
<table class="table table-striped border" id="datatable-table-4">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Col1</th>
                                                    <th>Col2</th>
                                                    <th>Col3</th>
                                                    <th>Col4 Datetime</th>
                                                    <th>Col5 Datetim</th> 
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @foreach (var item in Model.List)
                                                {
                                                    <tr class="odd">
                                                        <td>
                                                            @item.Name
                                                        </td>

                                                        ...
```

**NEW**

I added this code above the datatable

```
<div class="form-group row mt-4">
                                                  
        Minimum Date:
        <input name="min" id="min" type="text">

        Maximum Date:
        <input name="max" id="max" type="text">
    
    <label class="col-md-12 text-left">Category</label>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <select class="form-control w-100" onchange="categoryChange()" id="categorySelect">
            <option disabled selected value="0">Seçiniz</option>
            @{
                var list = Model.List2.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct().ToList();
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>

                }
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can show dropdown and also can get selected value but how can i filter it by selected value serverside.

Comment: Anyone to help me, I can make it

Comment: (1) The drop-downs work OK for me in the link you provided. Are you saying they are not working for you? Does the link show us what you actually tried, or only what you tried to copy from? (2) I am not sure what you are asking here, also. (3) To use buttons you need to [download](https://datatables.net/download/) the button extensions and also use the [`dom` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom). For example, `dom: 'Bfrtip'`.

Comment: I think it might be easier for the community to help you if you asked one question at a time, and provided the exact code you are using, instead of (or as well as) linking to other examples.